# PHP crawler - Problem with sites with different encodings

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, web-crawler, multilingual

I am building a keyword density analyser. I have build the keyword analyser which works absolutely fine with websites that have English content and UTF-8 encoding. When I crawl a website like myegy.com, the arabic keywords show up as question marks in my website. I have tried iconv and mb_convert_strings and both of them are **not** working.

I need help creating a keyword density program which is able to crawl all languages and encodings and store them in a database with utf-8 encoding and display them back...

I am a newbie on the encodings so your help will be really appreciated...

Displayed on my page as ����� and with iconv -> ÈÌæÏÉ. It should be displayed in arabic though which I am not able to show as the arabic is shown as the question marks.

Comment: When you say you've tried iconv, what did you do?  You need to read the Content-Type header *and* the 'content-type' meta tag to find where the encoding is specified, then iconv based on the detected encoding.

Comment: I have tried using mb_Detect_encoding as well as actually getting the encoding from the headers of the website and putting that in manually. Nothing is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myegy.com uses windows-1256 encoding. Iconv supports it. It should work, as long as you're finding the declaration and using `iconv` correctly.

When crawling the web, you'll find a lot of different encodings, some of them will be incorrectly named, some will be bogus. Lots of pages will lack encoding declarations and rely on browsers guessing the encoding.

If you want to support all encodings as well as possible, you will need to implement HTML5 encoding detection algorithm:

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/parsing.html#determining-the-character-encoding

Also note that PHP's built-in `DOMDocument::loadHTML()` supports very few encodings. You'll have to convert documents (and encoding declarations in them) to UTF-8 first.